# pdf files are opened by image magick

Tags: 16.04, pdf, imagemagick

pdf files are opened by imagemagick. if I uninstall imagemagick then the printer canon mf4350 starts malfunctioning

i am using ubuntu 16.04

please help

Comment: It's not clear what your question is, what the intended results are. Assuming you want the PDF file to open with a different software, all you have to is right-click > Properties and then open the "Open with..." tab, select the desired software and make it default.

Comment: Celtic warrior, I want to open pdf using evince or document viewer. but these file open with imagemagick.  I tried changing the default by right-clicking on the icons, but the default option does not change.

Comment: Same problem: If imagemagick is installed (i.e. default) then it cannot be removed from file association with PDF mime type. If it *is* removed,  then I can set the PDF Reader (or even Sumatra in wine) as the default application, but cannot proint with CUPS, etc.